# Assert Function In JavaScript

Tags: javascript, assert

I was given an exercise but I am not completely understanding the assert function that was given to me. So check this out..

```
function assert(input, expectedResult, descriptionOfCorrectResult) {
   if (!expectedResult) {
      console.log(descriptionOfCorrectResult);
   } else {
      console.log('test passed');
   }
};
```

So `!` gives us a boolean. So `if (!expectedResult)` should gives us a `true` or `false`. Let's use a simple function for example:

```
function square(x) {
  return x * x;
};
```

How would I use the assert function on this simple square function? Can that be done?

Comment: `assert(null, square(2) === 4, "2 squared should be four)`. I don't know what `input` is supposed to be; it's not used anywhere.

Comment: That assert function makes no sense at all.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you want to test `square(4)`. The first parameter* of `assert` contains the input you pass to `square`, the second is your actual test, and the third is when you explain what you're doing. So, you have:

```
assert(4, square(4) == 16, "The result of square(4) should be its square, 16.");
```

If it works it logs `"test passed"`; otherwise it gives you the error message, `"The result of square(4) should be its square, 16."`.

That's how to use it.

*Actually, since `assert` doesn't use the first parameter, what you put there really doesn't matter; the log output would be the same if you passed in the Gettysburg Address.

I have one other observation: if the assertion fails, the log doesn't include `square`'s output, it only tells you what the output should be. You probably want to know both. I'd lobby to change this function if I were you.